# django complex queries filter and create list

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

class or models

```
class Category(models.Model):

    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Product(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)


class ProductDetails(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    mfg = models.DateTimeField()
    exp = models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)


class product_barcode(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barcode = models.BigIntegerField()
    flag = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
```

1> first task 
find product_name,cost,flag?? using barcode value of product_barcode table

class S_history

```
class S_History(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
```

2> create list if S_History.barcode=prodcut_barcode.barcode

S_History table may contain multiple entries of same barcode

list look like

```
[{"product_name":"fff","cost":"999"},{"product_name":"xxxwww","cost":"55"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your First Query will look like below query

```
 product_detail = product_barcode.objects.filter().values('flag', 'ProductDetails__cost', 'ProductDetails__product__product_name')
```

2) For second query, you need object of product_barcode
and use

```
product_detail = S_History.objects.filter(barcode=product_barcode.barcode )
```

Comment: gives exceptions type object 'product_barcode' has no attribute 'barcode'

Comment: check for  product_barcode table contains barcode field